# How do I make OpenSSL write the RANDFILE on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, openssl

When I run:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to write 'random state'
    e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

My googling suggests this is some kind of Vista permissions issue. How can I allow Vista to write this file or how can I configure openssl to get round it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using openssl what does "unable to write 'random state'" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean)

Answer (score 62):

The root issue is that the RANDFILE variable in the OpenSSL configuration file is ignored on Windows.  This has been a [long-standing problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg09930.html) that continues to exist as of the OpenSSL v1.0a release, regardless of whether the target Windows platform is x86 or x64.

There is a delightfully simple solution, though. Merely use a regular environmental var to set the RANDFILE value, like

```
set RANDFILE=.rnd
```

Because this value is ephemeral, it must be re-issued for every new DOS box, or scripted in a batch file.

Comment: This fixed my issue on Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 4):

I found this that might help: [Using OpenSSL what does "unable to write 'random state'" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean)

also, here: http://adamyoung.net/OpenSSL-unable-to-write-random-state

there is a suggestion here http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg51344.html on how to get it working in vista.

find the location of cmd.exe, right click and run as administrator

Comment: It doesn't allow me to change the permissions for cmd.exe

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but for Windows 7.  Easily solved, I created a system Environment Variable called HOME and set it to the directory I wanted my .rnd file in.  This solved the issue because OpenSSL didn't know where my .rnd file was (because I didn't have one) and it didn't know where to put it if it was to create it.  As soon as I set my environment variable HOME with a directory (c:\ is fine!) I reran my key generation in OpenSSL and it worked straight off.  To verify, I checked the key I had created and it had proper content.  I also checked the directory I set my HOME environment variable to, and lo and behold a .rnd file was sat there!  Hope this helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `HOME` variable into your environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the script is missing some access rights or cant find the file.

The solution:

Create a system variable with the name **RANDFILE** and the value **%USERPROFILE%.rnd**

Notice the **%USERPROFILE%**, is a system variable that automatic inserts the path to your user profile.