# Can't install php Composer, complaining about openssl

Tags: composer-php, wampserver

I'm trying to install Composer. However, it's giving me an error about "...openssl extension is missing..." (please see screenshot)

[image]

In my wampserver configuration I've enabled openssl extension (please see screenshot)

[image]

Please advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install: OpenSSL + WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320529/how-to-install-openssl-wamp)

Comment: @LiamSorsby I'll try in the evening and get back about if this solves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The composer download, as far as I remember, uses the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) so in fact you have to include the php_openssl module into the PHP.INI used by the PHP CLI.

So edit the php.ini in the `\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` folder. You have to do this manually you cannot use the menu liks on wampmanager.

Just remove the comment `#` from column 1 of this line

```
#extension=php_openssl.dll
```