# Error expecting certificate request while signing a certificate in OpenSSL for apache

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wampserver, processmaker

I'm going to install SSL using OpenSSL on WAMPServer. The processes which I've been through are as follows:

1. I have installed apache, configured it and activated ssl module,
2. Added a new system variable OPENSSL_CONF:

   ```
       Variable name: OPENSSL_CONF
       Variable value: A:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf
   ```
3. Restarted windows and made sure I saw the following line among the environment variables using command-line set | more command:

   ```
       OPENSSL_CONF=A:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf
   ```
4. Installed openSSL1.01Light(x64) on A:\OpenSSL and in its bin folder I have generated a key using command line command:

   ```
       openssl req -new > webserver.csr

   (Note that openSSL installation directory by default ain't have webserver.csr and I had to copy it from A:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin directory)
   ```
5. The command ran and prompted me to enter a PEM pass phrase and verify it. I entered a pass phrase and verified it.
6. I entered information that would be incorporated into my certificate request.
7. I ran the following command:

   ```
       openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out webserver.key
   ```
8. I was prompted for the pass phrase from the previous step. The RSA key was written and the file webserver.key was then available in the folder.
9. Now I was going to covert the certificate into a signed one using the following command:

   ```
       openssl x509 -in webserver.csr -out webserver.cert -req -signkey webserver.key -days 365
   ```

I got stock in this level that error occured with the following message:

```
        5336:error:0906D06C:PEM routiness:PEM read bin:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
        error in x509
```

How do I overcome this issue? Any idea? Thanks...

Comment: This post should help you install an SSL certificate in WAMPServer. For example the system variable bit is not required. possible duplicate of [Installation SSL in wamp server: Error in httpd-ssl.conf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it did a lot of things. I managed ssl configuration on wamp server for the site step by step.

Comment: This process was to configure ProcessMaker to use SSL/TLS, but still I can't access to processmaker login page with "https" protocol. Here's the processmaker related documentation:

http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/2.0/Additional_Server_Configuration

I have problems with adding those 3 lines to httpd-vhost.conf for process maker:

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/apache.pem
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire

According to my specifications in my problem, how should I change "/etc/apache2/apache.pem"?

Comment: Those are unix instruction. Move your .pem file to lets say `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\ssl`  and then change the `SSLCertificateFile` parameter accordingly

Comment: @RiggsFolly Which .pem file should I move and to which directory?
I have \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\[ssl.crt | ssl.key] and I don't have any .pem file in apache or wamp directory. Do you mean I should copy it from OpenSSL binaries which I have installed in an other path?