# enabling ssl_module for apache in wamp 2.5 freezes apache

Tags: apache, wamp, mod-ssl

I'm trying to use openssl with php in wamp, I have found numerous old guides to do this but I can't even seem to enable ssl_module in httpd.conf. It makes the wamp system tray icon stay orange (even after restart etc).

Does anyone have some tips or an up to date guide on how to enable openssl on wamp 2.5? Been messing around for a few days now

I have ran the code below causing an error:

```
//error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new();
while($message = openssl_error_string()){
echo $message.'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

ANd other code produces this fatal error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'OpenSSL does not seem to be installed
```

I have installed Xampp (and turned of wamp) But I get the same errors) in info.php i see however:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015
```

Comment: Here is an answer that might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312

Comment: @RiggsFolly,, Thanks! sorry for the late reply. I'll have a look at the article. Cheers!