# One page can be loaded under different urls

Tags: javascript, html, wampserver

One page can be loaded under different urls

I have a local host site in this format:

```
localhost/test/test.html
```

in wampserver

I would like to make it to have different log option like the following:

```
localhost/test/test.html/
localhost/test/Test.html
https://localhost/test/test.html
```

How is it possible to make it in the html code of the test.html file?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/url-masking.php, But maybe google first before you ask because it only took me 2 sec to find it.

Comment: Its not possible to make that happen using just HTML. The first 2 urls would work just fine on windows as its not case sensitive, but would not work on a unix hosted server. If you want to setup SSL then you are going to do a lot more, [try reading this post for help on HTTPS/SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312)