# Wampserver: WARNING: can't open config file: ...openssl.cnf

Tags: wampserver

I'm following the [tutorial here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986) to set up HTTPS on Wampserver.

My wamp is @ `d:\wamp`

Everything has worked up until Step B, which says:

> Type the command:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

That command produces the error:

> WARNING: can't open config file:
>   c:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl/install_x86/openssl.cnf
>
> Unable to load config file info from:
>   C:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl/install_x86/openssl.cnf

I'm assuming I need to gain a copy of `C:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl` but I find no trace of this on Google, and do not know what it is.

Do you know where I can gain a copy of `C:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl` or `winlibs_openssl`?

**Edit**: I found https://github.com/winlibs/openssl

**Edit2**: I ran the following command in an elevated CMD prompt:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=d:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf
```

and then ran

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

again, and received the same error:

> WARNING: can't open config file:
>   c:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl/install_x86/openssl.cnf
>
> Unable to load config file info from:
>   C:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl/install_x86/openssl.cnf

PHP error log shows:

> [14-Apr-2016 09:38:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'd:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.
>
> [14-Apr-2016 09:38:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'd:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.

Comment: That last phrase `winlibs_openssl` prompted a Google search which found [https://github.com/winlibs/openssl](https://github.com/winlibs/openssl)

Comment: I copied `D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf` to a newly created `C:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl\install_x86` folder, and the error disappeared.

Comment: Did you not see that question was from 2008?

Comment: Have a look at this post, its a little newer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26252312/2310830

Comment: @RiggsFolly, add an answer to this question with the better solution, and I'll accept if if you like (to close the question).

Comment: Just give the linked answer an Upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this Q & A is worthwhile, but:

I copied `D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf` to a newly created `C:\vc11_deps\repo\winlibs_openssl\install_x86` folder, and the error disappeared.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me out (although I changed to install_x64 for the 64bit installation).  :)