# enable ssl on wamp64

Tags: ssl, openssl, wamp, ordinal

I'm trying to run ssl on wamp 64 . I've downloaded and installed Openssl "`Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2g`" from the site : http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html .

When I try to generate the private key (`openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048`) from the cmd I get this error :

`the ordinal 372 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\openssl.exe.`

any help ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation SSL in wamp server: Error in httpd-ssl.conf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf) This should help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that command `openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048` by changing the directory in cmd where openssl.exe file is present. I will recommend to you to use `openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048` command