# Apache failure to start. WAMP with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, https, localhost, wamp

I have a local development environment that is needing SSL. I cloned the environment from git hub, and it was using SSL, (do I need to create a self signing cert that is exactly like the one used?)After I got it working in just a regular unsecured environment, I followed this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf) to make it SSL.  However, since I started moving from an unsecured dev to a ssl dev environment, WAMP is failing to start.  I'm not even getting error logs anymore. The last one I got was from yesterday.  Also, trying httpd -k start gives the os10013 error "an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden"

```
[Tue Aug 16 13:21:56.086725 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2436:tid 348]
AH02311:Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. 
See C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/sslerror_log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Checked the SSL log and it's blank.

I also get the error, when trying to bring it online:

```
Could not execute menu item (internal error)[Exception] Could not
perform service action:The service has not been started
```

I figured this was a port conflict. I ran netstat -an and found nothing listening on ports 80,8080, or 448 (the ssl port I'm using), still nothing.

So I've ran out of ideas and need some help.  Below are the configs for my files.

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
Listen 443
Listen 445
Listen 448
<VirtualHost _default_:448>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/foo/bar"
ServerName foo.dev:448
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/wamp/logs/sslerror.log"
TransferLog "C:/wamp/logs/access.log"
SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
SSLCertificateKey "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.key/server.key
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/foo/bar">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local
</Directory>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8080
Listen 445
Listen 448
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
# 'Main' server configuration
ServerName localhost:80
HostnameLookups Off
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf 
#IncludeOptional "c:/wamp/vhosts/*"
Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/foo/bar"
ServerName foo.dev
ServerAlias www.foo.dev
<directory "c:/wamp/www/foo/bar">
AllowOverride All
Require local
</directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
ErrorLog "logs/local-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost-access" common
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
AllowOverride All
Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 foo.dev www.foo.dev
::1 drm.dev www.foo.dev
```

And the extension in PHP.ini is installed.