# Wamp SSL configuration throws 404

Tags: apache, ssl, configuration, wamp

I have a domain which is mapped to an ip address.

http://test.main.com works FINE. https://test.main.com DOES NOT works, getting 404 error.

Please help me to find out the problem

**Below is my httpd-ssl.con file**

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp"
    ServerName test.main.com:443
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ErrorLog "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/apache_error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

    SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/ServerCertificate.crt"        

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.key/rms_bldgot_com.key"        

    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/ChainBundle1.crt"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All

    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "C:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf

Comment: @HSharma i have followed those steps, but no luck

Comment: Check ssl_module in the Apache modules.
Check php_openssl in the PHP extensions.

Comment: @HSharma httpd -t result was OK, so all this configuration was done right.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that some other service is running on port 80. A solution could be to change the port on which is being listened

So change the port on which Wamp listens:

```
Click on Wamp server -> Apache -> httpd.conf
Change Listen 80 to something else, eg: Listen 81
I would also change Server Name localhost:80 to ServerName localhost:81
```

If you've done this, and saved httpd.conf, you have to restart the Wamp server. Then use localhost:81 as your root url.

So the urls will then look like

```
localhost:81/phpmyadmin
localhost:81/mysite_directory
```

Comment: @I think for SSL 443 is port, so it make difference i guess. I have commented #Listen 443 in httpd-ssl.conf, is it an issue

Comment: Try it out you never know

Comment: Try this as well --> click the WAMP icon then click "Put Online"

Comment: Put Online is done, i am able to access the url outside

Comment: so probably you will have to change the port it seems

Comment: changed 81, same issue

Comment: Check this out http://www.phpjoel.com/2011/04/07/installing-ssl-using-openssl-on-a-wamp-localhost/