# could not bind to address [::]:443 in Wamp

Tags: apache, https, wamp, wampserver

I am using wamp in windows machine to configure SSL to support https request

when I ran this command below

**httpd -e debug**

Getting below error

(OS 10013)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

**OS**: Windows

**Server**:Wamp(appache2.4.x)

[image]

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp"
ServerName test.main.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@localhost
ErrorLog "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/apache_error.log"
TransferLog "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/access.log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/ServerCertificate.crt"        

SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.key/rms_bldgot_com.key"        

SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/ssl.crt/ChainBundle1.crt"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All

Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
"%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

Comment: Is something else using 443?

Comment: Are you also running IIS or one of the bit that comes with it? What OS are you using?

Comment: am using windows and wmap server

Comment: Yes but do you also have IIS running. W10 installs it by default

Comment: No I don't have that, if I uncomment listent 443 in httpd-conf file wamp starts, but HTTP url works( http://domainname.com) works, HTTPS URL  does no works, any idea

Comment: You have to listen on 443 for SSL (HTTPS) to work

Comment: So maybe your HTTPS config is wrong, [see this for some ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added https-ssl.conf file question body, please have a look at that

Comment: Does that come with a `Listen 443`?

Comment: Also you are using Apache 2.4, so use Apache 2.4 syntax for the access privileges. Remove `Order Deny,Allow Allow from 127.0.0.1` and replace with `Require local`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128448/discussion-between-niran-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: Sorry dont have time for a chat

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added <Directory "D:/ews/liveenergy/myapp">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require local

</Directory> 
,

Yes httpd-ssl.conf comes with Listen 443, Still same issue