# Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server - %1 Error Still After Switching to OpenSSL 64-Bit

Tags: apache, openssl, 32bit-64bit, wampserver, mod-ssl

I am trying to setup SSL on WampServer. When I use the httpd -t command in the Apache directory, I receive this error:

```
 Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

I have a 64-bit computer, but am running WampServer 3.0.6 32-bit, with Apache 2.4.23. I originally downloaded Openssl 32-bit, and received this error. So I downloaded the 64-bit version, because that seemed to be the problem. I repeated the process of creating the key, certificate, etc. I also updated the system environment variable of openssl_conf to its path of the 64-bit version of Openssl. I still receive this error. Is there something I missed in changing the version to the 64-bit? Or something I'm missing in general?

I originally followed the tutorial for setting up OpenSSL listed as the top answer to this question: [Installation SSL in wamp server: Error in httpd-ssl.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My problem occurs after following all these steps.

Comment: If you are running 32bit WAMPServer you need the 32bit php_openssl

Comment: What version of openssl did you download and from where?

Comment: I originally downloaded the 32-bit verison of OpenSSL from here:

http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html