# Amazon EC2 wamp enable https

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, wamp

I recently got an Amazon EC2 Windows 2012 R2 and installed wamp. Everything is running fine, but i want to enable the https. My site is http://, but when I change it to https:// it says:

[image: Not Secure HTTPS://]

The security group has RD, HTTP 80 and HTTPS 443.

I don't know how to do it even after searching on google and youtube. When I changed certificates, apache is not running so I re-installed wamp again and again , all were failed attempts.

Comment: it's all free tier, so i don't have a load balancer, i don't need one yet, maybe soon, but i just want to settle the HTTPS Not Secure problem dilemma

Comment: have you added the required certificates& pems on the webserver?

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312