# Wampserver: Orange status after installing openssl

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wampserver

I've installed openssl on my wampserver (localhost) using this tutorial http://www.mytechblog.in/install-ssl-windows-localhost-wamp-http-ssl-https/.

Everything was fixed and when finding for errors in cmd using httpd -t it says "OK".

Now, when I'm trying to turn on wampserver it gets stuck on orange status. Skype is closed, and the only thing I can think of is that httpd-ssl.conf and httpd.conf - both are using the same port. I found out that wamp is using port 80 and openssl is using port 443. I've also tried to change both of them anyway and still getting orange status.

I hope you can help me solve this issue! Thanks (:

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: There are literally thousands of questions regarding this topic and they were answered. @jww

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when not running wamp as an administrator, can you verify you are launching wamp server as admin?

Comment: Just ran it as administrator and still shows the orange status - local server - 1 of 2 services running @Whapster71