# magento SSL certificate issue: unable to get local issuer certificate commercial certificate

Tags: php, magento, curl, certificate, wamp

I am using magento community edition 2.2 on wamp on windows server 2016. Whenever I am trying to Sign in to sync your Magento Marketplace purchases through System > Web Setup Wizard > System Config using the private and public keys taken from magento market place, I am getting the error:

"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

I tried solutions provided in some of the other threads in this forum to download cacert.pem and do the following settings in the php.ini

curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\cacert.pem" (this is where I put the cacert.pem file). It did not work!!

Other threads advice to put the self certified certificate in a convenient directory and specify the name with path for "curl.cainfo" and "openssl.cafile".

The issue is that I am not using self certified certificate. I have bought a commercial certificate, where they have given two files a certificate and a certificate chain file. Along with the key file I used to create the request, I have successfully installed configured apache to get https for the website.

The question is, how to get rid of the above error ""SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". The answers in the threads are all for the self signed certificates, where I am having a commercially purchased certificate (with multiple files)

I am using php 7.1.9 on wamp 3.1.0 magento CE 2.2.0

Please Advice....

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252312/2310830) is about Self Signed Certificates, but it should at least tell you where to install your certificate

Answer (score 0):

You must have received the root and the intermediate certificate along with the main certificate.

The error states that its unable to verify the certificate uptil the root certificate. Rename the CACert.pem file with .crt extension . Also change the extension of the public key to .crt. Now, verify Whether the  ISSUES BY of public key is the ISSUED TO of cartcert.pem is same. if its not the same then the intermediate in the cacert.pem is incorrect.