# Installing SSL on WAMP Server - Can Only Connect via HTTPS Sometimes

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, wamp

I am currently trying to install a self-signed SSL certificate on a wamp server (running apache 2.4.2).

I have almost word for word followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252312/8842926) to do so.

When trying to connect via https:// on chrome it nearly always fails, returning ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED or ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED but if you keep refreshing, it will sometimes connect as expected (though only 1 in 20 at best...)

I'm not particularly experienced with any of this, but if anyone can point me in the direction of something I may be doing wrong then that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If your server is up and you are able to browse the website with http:// then you need to check if the port 443 is open or not. Also, if you have proxy, firewall and load balancer then you need to check that port 443 is open on the same