# SSL installed on domain with wamp, but browser says "insecure"

Tags: apache, ssl, wampserver, windows-server-2012-r2

I followed this tutorial [Installation SSL in wamp server: Error in httpd-ssl.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf) to set up SSL on my server, but still the browser says "Site is insecure".

Windows server 2012R2
Wamp server 3.1.3 64 bit. 
Running Moodle on it.

Checked my domain on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ but got no errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding https to the moodle configuration file. Apache related configuration was fine according to the link provided above.

Cheers