# Apache: Port :443 used for the VirtualHost is not an Apache Listen port

Tags: wamp, wamp64

When viewing port 443 it is not being used by anything nor blocked
When I run wamp the port 443 is then open

Locally i can view my website via 443 which is setup in my vhosts but over the web i can not
I've never had this issue before and not sure why i am having it

**https-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    #Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mysite.com
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/mywebsite"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/mywebsite/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    #Require local
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/private.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
...

SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/private.key"
```

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

I checked with my isp and turns out they had all the traffic on my router going through port 443 but that is now fixed yet still unable to connect.

By default apache should listen on port 80 and 443 with ssl

I've gone through all my previous steps when setting up a site which have worked first time no issues in the past.

I've also checked that ports 443 and 80 are none blocking calling my isp to double check as it's a business router I was working on. same results with my home router.

I've also check C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and my site is displayed as 127.0.0.1 mysite.com
I shouldn't have to add :443 on the end which apache tells me to, trying this anyhow does not work neither.

Comment: No but you do have to add `https://` in front of the secure site to make it go via port 443

Comment: The virtual host for the secure port 443 should live in the `httpd-ssl.conf`

Comment: From tutorials I've read, they've setup a vhost on port 443 in httpd-vhosts.conf and in httpd-ssl.conf setup the default virtual host on port 443 locally, i will give it a shot changing information in httpd-ssl.conf as i can access port 443 locally.

Comment: Changing everything to https does not work though I am setup with cloudflare, I have a feeling that is messing with me, ether way cloudflare should be auto redirecting all traffic to https, but can't even access via http on port 443 which i should be able to from what i recall.

Comment: I've not changed anything within my code and my assumption was correct, cloudflare is the issue, I routed another domain that was presetup on cloudflare and this time 
redirects me via port 443, given http it auto redirects to https as expected.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help @RiggsFolly though your answer especially regarding needing https in front of the secure site to make it go via port 443 is wrong

Comment: You might like a liik at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312