# How to set up OpenSSL on Wamp with IIS?

Tags: apache, iis, openssl, wamp, httpd.conf

I installed openssl on my Wamp Server following the instructions found at [How to install: OpenSSL + WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320529/how-to-install-openssl-wamp). I have my setup in my `http.conf` file to currently listen to port 8080 in order to accommodate running Wamp along side IIS.

> ServerName localhost:8080

However, I cannot get my wamp server to run after I edit the `httpd-ssl.conf` file according to the instructions.

So my question is how do I run openSSL on Wamp along side IIS?

Comment: How do you know its not running? What is `netstat -a` output?

Answer (score 1):

Running 2 webserverse on the same server needs to have either different ports or differnet IPs.

You took the road using a different Port which is working but then you need to call your server with
https://localhost:8080/