# Can't start Apache: Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite'

Tags: openssl, wampserver

I'm trying to get SSL working with WampServer. I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095344/667903), and I get to the section: `Now test your Apache installation by calling httpd -t`.

Apache will not restart at this point. Windows error log has an entry:

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration     .
```

I can comment out `SSLCipherSuite` in:

- C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf
- C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\original\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

but then the next command down is reported in Windows Error Reporting as an invalid command.

Any pointers?

Comment: is mod_ssl enabled (with LoadModule)?

Comment: Try this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: `LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so` in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 11):

In the `httpd.conf`, need to turn on `mod_ssl.so`:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Then the next problem is to turn on `mod_socache_shmcb.so`:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and solved running the command:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile Apache httpd with enable-ssl option. If not, then recompile httpd with ssl and then add mod_ssl configuration.