# Apache server is not listening on SSL port 443

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I am trying to configure Apache server in REDHat Linux . Have used below configuration to configure apache configuration

```
./configure --enable-ssl --enable-so --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin/pcre-config --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

Before that I have install openssl , apr, apr-utl, pcre.

Once server is up I can only see port 80 available for listening. Https is not comming up. Have used below command as well to verify available ports listener

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

Any idea where exactly need to check for any possible issues ?

Comment: All what you show is how you compiled Apache. But for the run time Apache needs a configuration where it is defined on which ports it will listen and with which protocols and which certificates should be used for SSL etc. Given that you don't show this configuration you might need be aware that you need to configure anything in the first place. Please study the plenty of documentation then which shows how to configure Apache.

Comment: After placing certificate in place and enabling line  "Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf" line httpd.config , now getting error as 

Invalid command 'SSLCipherSuite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. Any possible solutions for the same?

Comment: I cannot look in your brain and I cannot see what you see and thus I have no idea what you are really doing. If you want help please provide sufficient information (exact error messages, full configuration) instead of only small snippets.

Comment: I have put configuration file , error logs and some screen in link below. Let me what additional information may be needed

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhTBbH1D0pB3hrw0I7hRiCGGQcwJbg?e=pdm6nz

Comment: You have not included the necessary module for SSL, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679639/cant-start-apache-invalid-command-sslciphersuite

Comment: ssl module I have installed using link as below..
https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-install-mod-ssl-on-redhat-64-server-031814

Also have shared ssl.config file in above link also. Please let me know what else I can check or share with you for your analysis.

Comment: I'm not talking about **installed** but about  **included**.  `mod_ssl` is not activated 
 in your configuration. Please follow the  information in question I've explicitly linked to.

Comment: I have tried to execute ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so and works fine but still when trying to start apache it's throwing error.

Comment: Sorry, but I give up to help you. It looks like that you are not able to follow information from other questions I've explicitly linked to. At least it looks for me this way since what you do seems to be unrelated to what is provided in the question and answers.  Maybe somebody else has more patience.

Comment: Link that you have marked is giving two pointers , mod_ssl is enabled or not & for me its alreday enabled working. And 2nd point loadmodule for mod_ssl.so on which I am getting error.

Comment: Just to update , I am able to solve this and bring back ssl port. Last error related with mod-ssl is solved by exporting the library for custom ssl library as "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/ssl/lib" and then started apache with same user. But i donn't know how to include this in script or make it genaric. As currently if I run just as normal user for export and start apache using sudo user it's not working.

Comment: You've installed apache and modules in a path which is not configured as default path. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=144967 on how to deal with this by adding this to the system-wide library path.