# Connection not secure for https://localhost running on wampserver?

Tags: debugging, localhost, ssl-certificate, wampserver

I'm a noob for server stuffs and I'm trying for the first time to run https://localhost on wampserver.

**Wampserver configuration**

```
wampserver version : 3.0.6
apache version : 2.4.23
```

I followed all instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320529/how-to-install-openssl-wamp/34297407#answer-25095344).

I did :

1. Add the **environment variable OPENSSL_CONF**
2. I managed to **generate a certificate** inside the bin folder and I moved them...

   - path-to-apache/conf/demoCA/certs/cacert.cert
   - path-to-apache/conf/demoCA/certs/cacert.csr
   - path-to-apache/conf/demoCA/private/cacert.pem
   - path-to-apache/conf/demoCA/private/cacert.key
3. And for the moment I desactivate virtualhost menu to **include httpd-ssl.conf**

   > Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
4. I configured **httpd-ssl.conf** file

   - DocumentRoot "path-to-wamp64/www"
   - ServerName localhost
   - ServerAdmin admin@localhost
   - CustomLog " path-to-apache/conf/ssl/logs/ssl_request.log"
   - SSLCertificateFile path-to-apache/conf/demoCA/certs/cacert.cert
   - SSLCertificateKeyFile path-to-apache/conf/demoCA/private/cacert.key
5. When I test via the command 'http -t', the synthax is Ok
6. I loaded the following apache modules :

   - **socache_shmcb_module**
   - **ssl_module**

And when I test https://localhost or https://localhost:443 or https://localhost/server-status/...
My browser says "connection is not secure !"

I don't know what I need to do to debug this.
Wampserver does not show me what is wrong.
Someone with knowledges could help me ?
How can I debug this, which tool for that ?

Comment: Please supply the **exact** error message you are getting

Comment: I cannot find any error message, that's my problem.

Comment: I have just the common message in my browser : "connection is not secure !".