# local WampServer https: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wampserver

**Edit**: It looks like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766320/wampserver-3-1-0-64-bit-redirecting-http-to-https) is the root cause. The site in question is a http site, but it redirects to https automatically, so I decided to install an SSL cert to see the outcome. /end edit.

I followed [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320529/how-to-install-openssl-wamp/25095344#25095344) to create a local SSL cert for my WampServer 3.1.0 64-bit.

I have made a local copy of our site, migrated the database to a new local URL (www.superiorit.dev), create an entry in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, and added a `<VirtualHost www.superiorit.dev:443>` entry in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf` which contains the correct path to the `.cert` and `.key` files.

When I try to load `https://www.superiorit.dev` in the browser, I receive the error:

> ```
> This site can’t be reached
> www.superiorit.dev refused to connect.
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> ```

This is the entry in `http-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost www.superiorit.dev:8080>
  ServerName www.superiorit.dev
  ServerAlias www.superiorit.dev
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/superiorit"
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/superiorit">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the entry in `http-ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost www.superiorit.dev:443>

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/superiorit"
ServerName www.superiorit.dev:443
ServerAdmin steve.doig@superiorit.dev
ErrorLog "c:/wamp64/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "c:/wamp64/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/conf/demoCA/cacert.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/conf/demoCA/private/cacert.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "c:/Apache24/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: any luck? i m facing same issue,if u can share your experience