# Unable to load Private Key

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to SSL/OpenSSL and I'm working on Windows 7. I'm trying to configure HTTPS for my ElasticBeanstalk environment following [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html).

I'm at Step 2 in "Create a Private Key".  After I issue the command to generate the key pair:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > privatekey.pem
```

I get:

```
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
........................................+++
...............................+++
unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

However, it does write a key to my directory. But after the second command:

```
openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem
```

I get:

```
unable to load Private Key
6312:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I've tried Googling this a bit, but none of the solutions I've found seem to be relevant for me.  I checked the generated key and it looks like

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 {lots of characters}
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

> unable to load Private Key
>   6312:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

I ran your commands on OS X, and I could not reproduce the results.

I *did* use the `-config` option because I have an "OpenSSL server config template" that makes it easy to generate CSRs and self signed certificates:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem -config example-com.conf
```

The configuration file is named `example-com.conf`, and you can find it at [How do I edit a self signed certificate created using openssl xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019957/how-do-i-edit-a-self-signed-certificate-created-using-openssl-xampp/26029695#26029695). Edit it to suit your taste (in particular, the DNS names).

If interested, here's the OpenSSL man pages on the [`req` sub-command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html).

---

> I checked the generated key and it looks like
>
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>   {lots of characters}
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

You can validate the key you just created with:

```
$ openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -inform PEM -text -noout
Private-Key: (2048 bit)
modulus:
    00:b0:91:ce:57:28:0f:5c:3a:c3:29:d7:23:6a:71:
    ca:64:49:fc:24:ea:69:a3:09:d6:49:94:17:b9:09:
    65:fa:5a:10:47:a4:9b:b8:cd:6d:32:74:19:8d:5c:
    79:92:f0:a6:43:9c:75:a3:7b:ef:c4:c3:d9:c2:db:
    b9:bd:ec:14:a8:b1:52:73:8f:56:c8:5c:16:08:56:
    ff:c2:2b:35:3c:0a:0f:34:d0:91:c1:54:7e:72:e8:
    97:bf:ea:46:69:5f:e4:21:8d:7a:f5:a5:6b:6a:e8:
    00:56:bc:02:f6:b4:ae:6e:89:a6:50:aa:5b:2f:d8:
    7d:99:04:61:51:76:b3:5e:9e:30:52:99:54:26:e2:
    3a:54:ec:78:34:e6:9a:b7:c2:58:5c:51:3d:39:52:
    d4:6e:0c:6e:a1:a0:a5:f1:4d:5a:f5:0b:1a:6e:dc:
    f3:bb:0d:d0:53:51:b0:1a:04:ee:86:35:d5:f3:8b:
    0d:bc:19:61:6c:0c:b2:7b:a9:7c:47:97:01:bb:a2:
    6a:74:d9:19:e9:df:60:07:d4:95:4c:83:f8:3b:84:
    c2:b8:3d:b9:a7:34:0a:9b:a3:c6:70:cc:ef:de:f4:
    64:88:f1:56:d3:2a:fd:5a:82:88:96:66:93:6c:a0:
    b8:ec:e4:4c:e8:76:5c:9c:fc:c4:60:72:b6:9a:3f:
    98:a3
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:87:ab:f1:65:ac:e5:68:93:ca:64:3a:e7:fe:a1:
    62:c7:7e:c5:dc:c3:b5:d9:cd:f4:36:e3:30:fb:40:
    0a:78:bc:7d:67:df:46:bc:50:34:88:a1:07:05:44:
    ba:31:ba:f1:b6:5f:e1:50:76:29:bd:02:54:2f:d2:
    cf:bc:ec:4a:cf:78:39:07:8c:6b:3d:56:ec:a3:09:
    de:49:9f:13:af:87:77:39:b8:cd:56:45:0b:48:56:
    0a:4c:2f:c2:5c:b3:8e:c2:6d:48:be:b9:95:79:36:
    bd:13:e8:31:4a:c9:78:82:7d:08:2b:51:4a:f1:cf:
    a2:6a:52:20:49:0d:31:34:10:88:02:d7:a7:07:70:
    32:b5:f5:8c:cc:d4:b2:8d:b9:aa:bb:33:82:1a:74:
    bd:4d:4f:e9:e0:cc:f2:27:fb:98:34:2c:77:56:6f:
    88:3a:66:32:5d:7d:57:c6:5b:63:39:fa:32:04:9d:
    e3:cc:a5:b6:44:91:fd:7d:d1:b6:2d:16:47:59:81:
    3d:cf:d9:a7:58:2a:d6:61:5d:c6:69:3b:7a:70:50:
    4f:80:f4:d9:fb:c8:7d:5e:44:9e:ac:c8:e6:aa:49:
    c3:d6:df:6b:03:68:25:a3:2b:89:8f:9a:35:3a:58:
    7d:71:b4:08:d9:04:7b:b9:96:17:f3:a5:19:c5:07:
    4e:c1
prime1:
    00:d7:d0:d8:8c:b5:86:ed:0e:06:70:c9:54:00:25:
    d7:8c:e4:65:51:1b:c5:ba:33:c2:02:1a:dc:80:a6:
    ae:8e:1e:e8:c0:b7:04:11:5a:e3:98:52:8f:4a:7a:
    43:b8:e8:1b:c8:d6:d3:b2:dc:70:59:a5:ca:83:bb:
    35:f1:6c:f5:cb:d0:f4:04:5e:aa:7c:d0:ec:d7:4a:
    d5:1c:7c:e2:67:e4:e8:17:95:9b:4e:2b:a0:26:74:
    61:d0:a0:15:27:18:e5:84:b5:54:ef:be:82:35:7e:
    78:e0:49:6b:4e:ae:93:53:a0:81:a3:8e:de:d3:e5:
    dc:c5:ba:03:36:14:47:97:03
prime2:
    00:d1:72:3b:f5:34:b1:11:78:b2:79:f4:3e:d7:be:
    bf:cc:b3:09:ea:24:a4:cc:7f:64:73:96:d2:48:9e:
    55:bc:79:23:c2:d9:80:81:7d:a4:a5:4b:43:33:8e:
    62:04:ec:8d:22:d7:43:5e:41:b6:4d:e9:b0:cc:70:
    63:17:70:93:88:81:f5:84:a6:3f:2b:98:33:a3:69:
    53:11:c7:95:8c:30:ea:e8:58:c7:77:10:b4:a8:f5:
    bf:5e:cf:e1:99:bb:b3:4e:57:d2:4c:f7:73:de:8a:
    98:8e:7c:26:37:6c:e4:77:c6:d2:ed:5d:53:a7:15:
    c3:9c:67:61:d3:24:9a:f5:e1
exponent1:
    00:83:34:59:e2:b9:9d:8c:d2:e1:01:82:b4:89:de:
    77:bc:15:42:af:5b:c6:0a:dc:da:8e:f3:0b:a9:3f:
    2c:92:04:a2:96:3e:ed:bf:2b:55:80:ce:78:84:db:
    ed:fe:25:46:77:04:7b:f1:9a:68:c7:67:ae:c6:05:
    73:d7:11:da:21:0e:28:bb:db:5d:a4:c2:53:aa:d3:
    b8:da:37:e6:61:29:5e:1c:b0:7c:99:ba:96:03:aa:
    ef:a8:a9:1a:13:09:e4:c7:98:82:49:ba:b5:68:96:
    3a:20:89:22:2e:d4:9d:86:d2:e6:dd:ab:c7:36:65:
    e1:a1:67:e3:f9:e5:bc:5c:47
exponent2:
    00:81:6d:b9:55:8f:09:39:05:c0:2d:12:dd:5e:cf:
    56:91:35:b6:93:c5:af:3d:5c:20:04:3a:18:9a:9d:
    95:d7:d1:78:62:e9:ab:ba:d9:9c:cc:34:95:43:9f:
    e2:3c:ae:bd:8c:e1:3f:95:58:c0:42:a7:7e:04:e8:
    12:a4:22:82:59:22:0e:49:b9:be:61:bf:3d:71:e7:
    1d:59:68:5f:a6:f1:77:c8:bb:4c:0f:ec:f7:e7:4d:
    6d:c4:36:6c:70:67:08:a8:0a:27:40:3e:ce:90:a0:
    4f:24:05:de:4b:f3:f3:bf:7c:d3:4d:b1:95:87:34:
    30:dc:4f:1a:a9:b2:fe:3b:a1
coefficient:
    6d:51:b3:6e:87:8d:aa:f0:55:c4:22:21:62:a9:ea:
    24:b3:b7:91:40:f5:78:5d:f1:40:45:7e:0d:a2:a3:
    54:46:ba:42:33:b6:cd:57:a1:85:bc:3d:ba:1c:eb:
    87:33:a9:e9:63:1e:7c:2c:89:98:b9:0f:4b:e8:c4:
    79:bd:00:6a:f5:3e:ea:63:f1:9e:aa:47:35:5a:22:
    fc:4e:e3:61:7e:eb:dc:a6:c0:2c:d5:fd:22:9f:01:
    59:32:15:db:41:99:b7:a8:c1:eb:1e:42:c7:1b:c7:
    c8:56:86:a8:34:fe:1c:48:b6:6e:f1:c1:5c:96:bf:
    9d:fa:e5:4c:d0:2a:d9:09
```

---

> unable to write 'random state'

This is a well known problem. OpenSSL uses a default configuration file. You can locate the configuration file with [correct location of openssl.cnf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21477210/608639).

The default configuration file includes these lines:

```
$ cat /usr/local/ssl/macosx-x64/openssl.cnf 
...
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
...
```

To save the random file, you should point `HOME` and `RANDFILE` to a valid location. On Windows, you type `set HOME=...` and `set RANDFILE=...` in the command prompt. Or better, change it in the OpenSSL configuration file you use.

Also see [How to fix “unable to write 'random state' ” in openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12507277/608639) and [How do I make OpenSSL write the RANDFILE on Windows Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2229723/608639).

---

> I'm trying to configure HTTPS for my ElasticBeanstalk environment following these instructions.

The instructions are wrong in the image below. ***Do not place a DNS name in the Common Name (CN)***.

[image]

Placing a DNS name in the Common Name is deprecated by both the IETF (the folks who publish RFCs) and the CA/B Forums (the cartel where browsers and CAs collude). You should pay articular attention to what the CA/B recommends because Browsers and CAs come up with those rules, and the browsers follow them (and they don't follow the RFCs). For reference, see [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt), [RFC 6125](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6125.txt) and the [CA/B Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/).

Instead, ***place DNS names in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN)***. Both the IETF and CA/B specifies it.

The custom OpenSSL configuration file handles this for you. You just have to change the DNS names listed under the section `[ alternate_names ]`. For example, here's a set of names set up for the domain `example.com`. Notice there is no DNS name in the CN:

```
[ subject ]
...
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = Example Company

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = example.com
DNS.2       = www.example.com
DNS.3       = mail.example.com
DNS.4       = ftp.example.com
```

Comment: I don't think keyform would help since PEM is the default anyways (according to the docs).  -nodes seems not be a good solution since "if this option is specified then if a private key is created it will not be encrypted".  The whole point is that its encrypted, no? In any case, I don't think I can upload a key encrypted with a passphrase.

Comment: @ethan123 - you're right. I was not able to reproduce your results on OS X. What OS are you using?

Comment: @ethan123 - I updated the answer to include instructions to test the key with the `openssl rsa` command.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you have appropriate permissions when you run both the commands? Maybe try doing the same using a user with Admin Rights.

Also make sure the created file privatekey.pem has appropriate permissions before executing the command below (Use chmod if necessary)

```
 openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out csr.pem
```

Submitting this as answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the root of the problem is the error

`unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)`

Searching StackOverflow found these results. I would stress that you run the openssl program as `sudo` or directly as root to avoid any possible permissions issues.

The fix in Windows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522479/3765769

In Linux:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/94458/3765769

Comment: *"I would stress that you run the openssl program as sudo or directly as root to avoid any possible permissions issues"* - that's usually a bad idea. The idea is to avoid root for standard commands, and use it only when needed.

Comment: @Mark I saw this solution and tried it.  It didn't work for me