# How to fix "unable to write 'random state' " in openssl

Tags: windows, openssl

While generating the private key using this command

```
genrsa -out my-prvkey.pem 1024
```

It throws the error like below

> Loadind 'screen' into random state -done Generating RSA private
>   key,1024 bit long modulus
>   .........................................+++++++
>   ...........................+++++++++ unable to write 'random state' e
>   is 65537 (0*10001)

This makes any problem while creating a public certificate. I'm running this command in windows. Can anyone help me for the fix?

Comment: This should be reopened, if not on stackoverflow.com, on superuser.com.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290001/715269

Answer (score 125):

The quickest solution is: set environment variable **RANDFILE** to path where the 'random state' file can be written (of course check the file access permissions), eg. in your command prompt:

```
set RANDFILE=C:\MyDir\.rnd
openssl genrsa -out my-prvkey.pem 1024
```

More explanations:
OpenSSL on Windows tries to save the 'random state' file in the following order:

1. Path taken from **RANDFILE** environment variable
2. If **HOME** environment variable is set then : **${HOME}\.rnd**
3. **C:\.rnd**

I'm pretty sure that in your case it ends up trying to save it in *C:\.rnd* (and it fails because lack of sufficient access rights). Unfortunately OpenSSL does not print the path that is actually tries to use in any error messages.

Comment: Sorry it was closed, mate... this is a great question and google brings it up first.

Comment: This also works great without having to run as admin. (Though just setting `HOME` was sufficient.)

Comment: If you're using PowerShell you'll want to use `$env:RANDFILE = 'C:\MyDir\.rnd'` (In PowerShell `set` is an alias for `Set-Variable` which has nothing to do with environment variables!)

Answer (score 37):

It may also be that you need to run the console as an administrator. On windows 7,  hold <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> when you launch the console window.

Comment: I feel this probably should have been a country unless you know this is a fix, but you prose suggests otherwise

Comment: you can also gain admin access to cmd by hitting Start, type cmd, right click cmd.exe, and run-as-administrator. :)

Answer (score 33):

just enter this line in the command line :

```
set RANDFILE=.rnd
```

Comment: I have install openssl on windows 10, I have run above command on command prompt. openssl still gives the same error as, OpenSSL> genrsa -out key.pem
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 512 bit long modulus
.....................................................++++++++++++
.......++++++++++++
unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)

Answer (score 7):

Or this in windows powershell

```
$env:RANDFILE=".rnd"
```

Answer (score 4):

I did not find where the .rnd file is so I ran the cmd as administrator and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

- Download openssl for windows from https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads
- Set Environment variable to the path variable as path="C:\your_folder\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin"
- Run below commands on the same path of bin
  [image]