# Signing a message with privateKey (elliptic p256)

Tags: java, node.js, cryptojs

How do we sign a message with a givenPrivateKey in java with elliptic curve(p256)

Basically a java implementation of

```
let elliptic = new EC('p256')
const sig = elliptic.sign(msgHashHex, privateKey, null)
```

I dont want to generate new private/public key pair. My privateKey = 'abc'

Also please let me know if there is an online tool to play around with digital signatures.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrivateKey privateKey = ; // your  EC p256 private key
byte[] msgHashHex = ; // byte array data

Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("ECDSA"); // or SHA256WithECDSA etc.
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(msgHashHex);   
byte[] result = signature.sign();
```

Comment: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: ECDSA Signature not available

Comment: Also how to convert String 'abc' to PrivateKey object

Comment: Your private key is ```abc```? It is not even a valid EC private key. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963581/reading-elliptic-curve-private-key-from-file-with-bouncycastle

Comment: Is it not possible to just sign message with a string ?

Comment: You can get ```byte[]``` message using ```String::getBytes```. As for the private key, if you already have the private/public key pair,  you can get the encoded key either ```byte[]``` or ```String```.