# Convert elliptic curve private key to (unencrypted) PKCS#8 format

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to convert EC private key

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIE2tzb8O0gBVw2IFOB/B8l1Ztjax3ut4DeNtuC3UMmZ6oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEayT6Tv8zZlpIUOKHEYnmsKZyTaqOHajL0InS4c5tK4fhkHZDSWUa
3tPl1ibIXt0LvaxHk47h0Tc4SGr3Ex8Bhg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

to Private Key

```
 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgTa3Nvw7SAFXDYgU4
H8HyXVm2NrHe63gN4224LdQyZnqhRANCAARrJPpO/zNmWkhQ4ocRieawpnJNqo4d
qMvQidLhzm0rh+GQdkNJZRre0+XWJshe3Qu9rEeTjuHRNzhIavcTHwGG
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

It's very easy when you execute openSsl command like this:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in ec1.pem -out ec2.pem
```

But i want to do this in Java way and didn't find any solution (tried so many from stackoverflow).
So i have for now following class:

```
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec ecNamedCurveParameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime256v1");
        KeyPairGenerator keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");

        // Create a secure random number generator using the SHA1PRNG algorithm
        SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        keyPair.initialize(ecNamedCurveParameterSpec, secureRandomGenerator);
```

Then i generate KeyPair and get PrivateKey in ECPrivateKey Object:

```
KeyPair pair =keyPair.generateKeyPair();
ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        try (JcaPEMWriter jcaPEMWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(sw);) {
            jcaPEMWriter.writeObject(privateKey);
        }

String pemFormat = sw.toString();
```

This string pemFormat is actually PEM format that starts with `BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY`

How can i convert it just to `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`?

I assume that should be a way if openSsl can do it.

Comment: This bog post may help: [Create and read PKCS #8 format private key in java program.](http://techxperiment.blogspot.com/2016/10/create-and-read-pkcs-8-format-private.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A conversion from the SEC1/PEM (`-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----...`) to the PKCS#8/PEM format (`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...`) is not needed at all, because [`privateKey.getEncoded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded()) returns the key already in PKCS#8 format. So it only needs to be exported as PEM e.g. with a [`PemWriter`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemWriter.html):

```js
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;

...

// Your code
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
...
ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();
System.out.println(privateKey.getFormat()); // PKCS#8

// Export as PKCS#8 PEM encoded key via PemWriter
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
try (PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(stringWriter)){
    pemWriter.writeObject((PemObjectGenerator)new PemObject("PRIVATE KEY", privateKey.getEncoded()));
}
String pkcs8PEM = stringWriter.toString();
System.out.println(pkcs8PEM); // -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----MIGTAg...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You can check the format in an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js.

---

However, if you are really looking for an explicit conversion of a SEC1/PEM key into a PKCS#8/PEM key, then the import of a SEC1/PEM key is described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41947163/9014097). The imported key can then be exported as a PKCS#8/PEM key using a `PemWriter` as in the example above.

Comment: Thanks!!! It really helped me to handle. I also checked by converting back to EC pem format and the same value.

Comment: What's the type of pair object in "(ECPrivateKey)pair.getPrivate()". I am trying to read my key from a String and return PrivateKey object. Can you share what do I need to update in the above snippet?

Comment: @dhamu - Please post a new question with all the information needed to answer. If necessary you can reference this post.