# RestTemplate certificate issue

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, https, resttemplate

I am passing certificates in RestTemplate request header. I get 403 forbidden error. How can I display the certificate information at my end before I make a call to the web service? I am using below code to pass certificate in request header.

[What is the right way to send a client certificate with every request made by the resttemplate in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713593/what-is-the-right-way-to-send-a-client-certificate-with-every-request-made-by-th)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 403 as I'm newbie on certs & stuff, but for your other questions(I know this is late but might help someone who come across to this page) :

**Java Keytool Commands for Checking :**

*keytool comes with JDK*

If you need to check the information within a certificate, or Java keystore, use these commands.

Check a stand-alone certificate :

> keytool -printcert -v -file mydomain.crt

Check which certificates are in a Java keystore :

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks

Check a particular keystore entry using an alias :

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias mydomain

First, I would suggest to verify in your rest client whether you're able to access the rest endpoint or not by importing cert & key files:

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates

Helpful links:

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html