# How to configure a server(Fargate, Docker, spring boot) calling an external rest api using mTLS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, aws-fargate, mtls

We have service which does a bunch of things, but also calls a 3rd party REST service. The supplier demands mTLS a sthe data is pretty sensitive. The service is a spring boot, running on Fargate/docker. All search points to App mesh or Api gateway - both are out of context. Any documentation or pointers on how this can be achieved? thanks.

Comment: I suggest you focus the question. Are you asking how mTLS works, how to provide secrets to Fargate, which libraries to use in Springboot, how to call API's? I'm genuinely not clear. What have you tried? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

> All search points to App mesh or Api gateway

No, App Mesh is for your internal network calls only, and API Gateway would be for incoming calls to your application, not outgoing calls. Neither of those services are relevant to your problem at all.

You simply need to configure your Spring Boot app to use a client-side certificate when it makes those external API calls. There is no AWS service that can really help you with that, it's all Java/Spring code, and the exact solution depends on exactly what library/method you are using to make those API calls.

You could package the client certificate into your docker image, or have your docker container pull it from S3 after it starts, or map an EFS volume to your ECS Fargate task and store the client certificate on that volume, or you might look into storing it in AWS Secrets Manager. After you tackle the problem of making the certificate available to your Java app, it's just a matter of telling your Java app to use that client certificate in the API call. There are plenty of other answers on this site that detail how to do that, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713593/what-is-the-right-way-to-send-a-client-certificate-with-every-request-made-by-th).