# Convert .pem and .key to .jks for Jenkins HTTPS

Tags: ssl, encoding, https, openssl, jks

I have a certificate provided by my company, one .pem file and one .key file as follows:

.pem file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{THE CERTIFICATE KEY}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

.key file

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
{THE KEY}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I need to obtain a .jks file because that's the only format accepted by Jenkins (I'm trying to enable HTTPS)

I tried to concatenate the two files and follow the steps described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296312/convert-certificate-from-pem-into-jks/22298627), specifically:

```
mv cert_private_key.key cert_private_key.pem    
cat cert_private_key.pem cert_public_key.pem | openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.p12
```

as the next step would be to convert the .p12 file to .jks, but the console just hangs or I get an "unable to load private key" / "unable to load certificates"

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pkcs12 -in certificate.pem -inkey certificate.key
```

worked. Make sure to use the official OpenSSL