# Configure Kafka client with ca cert (.crt or .pem)

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, debezium

I am using debezium to configure kafka connect using SASL_SSL. While the SASL authentication configuration I could do like below:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=${KAFKA_USERNAME} password=${KAFKA_PASSWORD};"
```

I could not find any documentation around configuring CA location using .crt or pem file. In C# or Python clients based on librdkafka I can set below properties:

```
ssl.ca.location = 'path/to/ca/file/ca-bundle.crt (pem also works)
```

However for Java clients(debezium based on Java) I see only truststore in jks format.
How do I configure it to use similar to client's mentioned above ?
Is something like below valid for java clients?

```
ssl.truststore.type = PEM
ssl.truststore.location='path/to/ca/file/ca-bundle.crt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Java truststores and keystores can only be JKS files. If you only have PEM/CRT files, you need to [convert them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296312/convert-certificate-from-pem-into-jks)