# WAMP is unable to generate private key when using OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl, wamp

I am working on OpenSSL in Windows 8.1, Wamp Apache Version: 2.4.9  PHP Version: 5.5.12. And I ended up with the following error:

[image]

My PHP code is given below. WAMP is unable to generate private key.

```php
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 384,      // Size of Key.
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $privKey, null, ['config' =>   'C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/openssl.cnf']);
$a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);

file_put_contents('keys/'.$username.'_public.key', $a_key['key']);
file_put_contents('keys/'.$username.'_private.key', $privKey);
openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```

Can anyone please help me in running OpenSSL in Windows. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some OpenSSL failures on Windows are related to the ***`.rnd`*** file and saving its state. See, for example, [How to fix “unable to write 'random state' ” in openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12507277/608639).

Comment: What, exactly, is the error you are trying to fix? The question seems to be changing as folks help you with your problem.

Comment: @jww I was not able to generate public and private key using openssl in wamp. Which is solved now. The answer below solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't much specific but I can say that you're calling `openssl_pkey_export` with wrong fourth argument. It should be array with `config` key instead of just string. `config` key is needed also for `openssl_pkey_new`.

```
<?php

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new([
    'private_key_bits' => 384,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    'config' => 'C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/openssl.cnf'
]);

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $privKey, null, [
    'config' => 'C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/openssl.cnf'
]);

$a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);

var_dump($privKey); // Just to test output

file_put_contents('keys/'.$username.'_public.key', $a_key['key']);
file_put_contents('keys/'.$username.'_private.key', $privKey);

openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```

Hope that's help

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking the time to help me here. I tried the code given above. It still produces the same warning. Warning: openssl_pkey_export(): cannot get key from parameter 1

Comment: The other errors are linked to the first one. Once this is fixed those will not be a problem.

Comment: No, it isn't produce same warning. Original warning was `... expects parameter 4 to be array ...`. It's solved. Now, you have problem with content of `$privateKey` variable (warning `... cannot get key from parameter 1 ...`). As I said, I can't help you more without whole source code.

Comment: Please check the code above. I have edited the post.

Comment: Well, I think `openssl_pkey_new` function needs also `config` key in configuration array. Try to dump value of `$privateKey`. I guess it will be `false`.

Comment: I added config key as you said. The error is solved but the key is generated as following `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MEwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADOwAwOAIxALxt85c/oYLMqn7GW2RDZBBs59ho2Y8u 8CUINbMG4Pqm1zpV3S2a0dImVJb0P8CB7QIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY----- ` And it generates the same key every time. It should not generate the header and footer along with the key

Comment: It's too many questions. Two things - private key is in PEM format. Header and footer are valid then. Are you sure it really generates same key every time? I edited my answer to reflect your updated question.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I tried 2 times after fixing `openssl_pkey_new` as you suggested. I also tried once more now. It is generating same key every time.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what to say more. Everytime if I run final version of script on my system (Windows 7, PHP 5.5.28), the PEM formatted private key is not the same. I inspect output by `var_dump` in the middle of script. If you think that it's another issue, you can create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem and I figured out, that WAMPserver do not have default CA installed. How to fix it:

- Install OpenSSL from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
- Copy `[OpenSSL-Win64]\bin\PEM\demoCA\` to `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\demoCA\`
- Restart WampServer

Also make sure that `OPENSSL_CONF` environmental variable is set to `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\openssl.cnf`