# Random Number Error with Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: openssl, self-signed

I have been trying to create a self-signed certificate but I keep getting an error related to the random number generator. I entered this in the terminal:

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

I then get the prompt to enter my information. I get through that just fine but when I press enter, I get the following error:

```
Cannot write random bytes:

139680915939776:error:2407007A:random number generator:RAND_write_file:Not a regular file:crypto/rand/randfile.c:163:Filename=/home/user/.rnd
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue on a raspberry pi3

Answer (score 1):

openssl needs a file which stores 256 bytes of seed data; it has to both read and write this file. The default name of this file is `.rnd`, but its location varies by system. In your case, it's `/home/user/.rnd`, which presumably doesn't exist.

Instead of relying on the default name, you can set the location in the `RANDFILE` environment variable, or assign it to `RANDFILE` in an openssl configuration file.

Before running openssl, write 256 bytes of random data to this file:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=randfile bs=256 count=1
```

This creates file 'randfile', so put this file name in your config file, or assign it to the `RANDFILE` envvar, or change it to `.rnd`.

@Maleka: The issue with Dovecot is that `RANDFILE` is set incorrectly in `dovecot-openssl.conf`. The original is:

```
RANDFILE = /dev/urandom
```

This won't work, since /dev/urandom is a special file and you can't write to it. Create 'randfile' as above, and change this line to

```
 RANDFILE = randfile
```

See also [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/177512).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using the following code as a replacement for /usr/share/dovecot/**dovecot-openssl.cnf** content:

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
encrypt_key = yes
distinguished_name = req_dn
x509_extensions = cert_type
prompt = no

[ req_dn ]
# country (2 letter code)
#C=FI

# State or Province Name (full name)
#ST=

# Locality Name (eg. city)
#L=Helsinki

# Organization (eg. company)
#O=Dovecot

# Organizational Unit Name (eg. section)
OU=IMAP server

# Common Name (*.example.com is also possible)
CN=imap.example.com

# E-mail contact
emailAddress=postmaster@example.com

[ cert_type ]
nsCertType = server
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are not allowed to write `/home/user/.rnd` with the user running the command.

You might want to check your access rights or if `/home/user` exists.

Comment: I came to this conclusion when reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522479/1268414.