# What is /dev/arandom?

Tags: php, linux, session, random

This [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-file) says:

> **Note**: As of PHP 5.4.0 session.entropy_file defaults to `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/arandom` if it is available. In PHP 5.3.0 this
>   directive is left empty by default.

So, what's `/dev/arandom` and how does it differ from `/dev/[u]random`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I can infer that from the path. What does the `a` stand for?

Comment: ARC4, according to the first result on Google. https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man4/arandom.htm

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That's the 6th result in my Google... Well, post it as an answer and I'll accept it. =)

Comment: My answer was closed but still I thought the thing is not to debate which a/q site has the most open/close answers but how to make the OP to find the answer to the question. The answer beyond the link still answered the question `What is /dev/arandom?`

Comment: @budwiser: I glanced at that website (1st result on my Google) before asking the question. The answer isn't obviously stated and some of the contributions are confusing and even misleading.

Comment: @Alix Axel That is somewhat given. But the thing you asked was **WHAT IT IS**, not how it works.

Comment: @budwiser: Sure. I also asked how it differs from other random sources. The link we saw didn't answered that, in fact the administrator of that site says that `/dev/arandom` doesn't exists. If your question was accepted, it would just cause confusion for everyone else wondering the same thing, don't you agree?

Comment: @Alix Axel 1) I didn't make a question, I made an answer 2) I didn't protest against it wasn't accepted, I wanted it **NOT to be deleted**.

Comment: @budwiser: Well, I didn't vote to delete it. I'm gonna do the opposite in fact, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [here](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/openbsd/man4/arandom.4.html).  It appears as though `arandom` will guarantee that sufficient entropy is present before returning the amount of data requested.  It also appears to be limited to OpenBSD implementations.  `urandom` will return the amount of data requested no matter whether there is enough entropy -- which obviously could introduce a vulnerability if there is not enough.

Comment: From https://calomel.org/entropy_random_number_generators.html: "`/dev/random` has very good entropy, but poor speed. `/dev/urandom` has poor entropy and good speed. `/dev/arandom` on an OpenBSD box has both".

Comment: @AlixAxel excellent distillation.  That was the gist I got from poking around as well, although I never found it so succinctly stated.

Comment: @Alix Axel: by "has both" do you mean "poor entropy and poor speed" ?

Comment: @sirgeorge: Not "poor", "very good". But the words aren't mine.

Comment: @ChrisThompson This answer is factually incorrect. `arandom` implemented on *BSD systems uses `arc4random` (currently based on the ChaCha20 stream cipher) to generate the stream of random bytes. Like `urandom` it will _always_ have enough data, there is no waiting. It has a higher entropy than traditional `urandom`, and as of OpenBSD 5.1 `arandom` replaces `urandom`. I would hate it if people read your answer and avoided `arandom` for fear of it blocking. It does not block, ever! :)

Answer (score 4):

[This page](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man4/arandom.htm) does a reasonable job explaining what the device is:

> As required, entropy pool data re-seeds an ARC4 generator, which then generates high-quality pseudo-random output data.

More information about the underlying technique is available [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).