# I try to generate Certificate Request- error "unable to write "random state" e is 65537

Tags: openssl

I am working on create certificate signing request for my server. when I run:

```
openssl genrsa -out www.mysite.com.key 2048
```

I got the error msg

```
"unable to write "random state" 
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

Could anyone help me? please!

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using openssl what does “unable to write 'random state'” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290001/715269

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the command as a superuser, like:

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out www.mysite.com.key 2048
```