# phpinfo shows different openssl version than I have installed

Tags: php, zend-framework, openssl, centos, centos6

`phpinfo()` reports I'm using OpenSSL 0.9.8y and has a configure command containing `'--with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8y'`.  When I do a `yum info openssl` it shows that OpenSSL 1.0.1e is installed.

Do I need to recompile PHP to fix th? Since I'm using Zend Sever CE, is this the right process to correct my issue with openssl in PHP?
http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/zend-server.htm#compiling_php_extensions.htm

What scenario do I use in the link above and what steps would I use specifically for openssl?

*NOTE: I am using CentOS 6.5, Zend Server CE 6.3, and PHP 5.4. The above is a link to docs for Zend Server CE 6.2 and I have 6.3 but I suspect it would be the same process???*

Comment: PHP will use the version of openssl that it was compiled against, not the version that you have installed (unless you built from source yourself against a specific version of openssl)

Comment: But if you are going to do a manual build yourself with a higher version of openssl, make sure that it's with version 1.0.1g, not the 1.0.1e that you have installed, as 1.0.1e is susceptible to heartbleed

Comment: @MarkBaker SSL for the connection between the browser and the server comes from Apache, not PHP, so would it really be a big deal if a vulnerable version was used with PHP?

Comment: First, how do I get 1.0.1g because I only see 1.0.1e when doing a yum update openssl? Second, which scenario do I use [from the link in my question](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/zend-server.htm#compiling_php_extensions.htm)... **Compile A PECL extension** or **Compile a PHP Extension Included in the Main PHP Source**?

Comment: @god_is_love if that's the version available from the official repositories, then it should be fixed. You can also test it by going to http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/ (remember to restart your http server first).

Comment: If you're using OpenSSL from PHP (e.g. using curl or similar), then PHP will use the version of openssl that it was compiled against; and you don't need it enabled for PHP unless you're using it like this.... so you don't need it enabled in PHP for the browser/webserver connection

Comment: @Mike Other symptoms on the server come from error logs:
    "Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus
    ....++++++
    ................................++++++
    unable to write 'random state'
    e is 65537 (0x10001)"
Also logging into the backend of a TYPO3 CMS instance on this server I get the error message:
    "PHP OpenSSL extension not working
    Something went wrong while trying to create a new private key for testing. Please check the integration of the PHP OpenSSL extension and if it is installed correctly."

Comment: @god_is_love See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean

Comment: @Mike I have already tried doing `rm ~/.rnd` for the root user and don't see any more .rnd files on my server. I had already [asked a question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469249/php-error-log-unable-to-write-random-state-e-is-65537-0x10001) but got not response so far.