# Unable to write 'random state'

Tags: openssl, embedded

OpenSSL application is throwing "unable to write 'random state'" error when creating self signed certificate.

I found [Using OpenSSL what does "unable to write 'random state'" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean) and learned that this is the case of version newer than 0.9.6a, and deleting or changing ownership of `.rnd` or running as root will solve the problem. But we are using embedded Linux with busy box so we don't have `sudo/su` utility and also the file system is a read only file system.

I am calling the OpenSSL app from a application using `system()`. Please help is there any other way to resolve it.

Comment: So I'm clear (I don't have a Busybox device to test on): doing a `export RANDFILE=/tmp` or `export RANDFILE=/dev/null` does not work? You should also show the code calling `system()` since it could be relevant.

Comment: "But we are using embedded Linux with busy box so we don't have sudo/su utility and also the file system is a read only file system."  If that is actually related to the issue, it sounds like you need to learn a bit more about managing your embedded linux installation.  Perhaps you should symlink the file in question to a tmpfs partition, or even switch to a scheme where your running filesystem is either a ramdisk uncompressed from flash, or some kind of union of a tmpfs atop a read only flash file system.

Comment: @Chris - good observation. But Busybox is not the easiest to work with (speaking from experience). He may need to bring in a consultant, but the budget may not have the room.

Comment: From application i did "export RANDFILE=/dev/null" and then i ran openssl, using system(). But it didn't work, the mistake i did was i used two different system() calls. But when i used both commands in a single call it worked. But isn't there a permanent solution rather than calling export every time .