# Unable to write 'random state' e is 65537 (0x10001)

Tags: ios, windows-7, openssl, phonegap-build

Right now I am building a hybrid app using PhoneGap. To make my app available for Apple devices I need an iOS signing key that I can upload to PhoneGap Build. This
[tutorial](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows) explains how to build an iOS signing key on Windows using OpenSSL. I followd this tutorial and installed OpenSSL-Win 64, but every time I run this command : `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ios.key 2048` I get de following error message: `OpenSSL unable to write 'random state' e is 65537 (0x10001)`

I did some research on the internet and some people are say that you need a HOME system variable. So I created one on my Windows laptop and the location of my HOME variable is `C:\`. I ran the command `OpenSSL unable to write 'random state' e is 65537 (0x10001)` again but I still received the same error message.

I hope someone can help me because I don't know what I am doing wrong! :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290001/715269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I receive the same error unless I am running OpenSSL as administrator.

Right click OpenSSL and try `Run as administrator` and try the command again. That gets rid of the error message for me.

Additional notes from the OpenSSL FAQ:

> ### 2. Why do I get an "unable to write 'random state'" error message?
>
> Sometimes the openssl command line utility does not abort with a "PRNG
> not seeded" error message, but complains that it is "unable to write
> 'random state'". This message refers to the default seeding file (see
> previous answer). A possible reason is that no default filename is
> known because neither RANDFILE nor HOME is set. (Versions up to 0.9.6
> used file ".rnd" in the current directory in this case, but this has
> changed with 0.9.6a.)

[Here is a link to the FAQ](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#USER2), including the "previous question" that it refers to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric but even when I am running OpenSSL as administrator I still get the error message e is 65537 (0x10001). Do you have an other solution?

Comment: The `e is 65537` is not part of the error. `e` is a prime number used in the RSA encryption algorithm. You can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation. I'll update my answer with everything else I've found, though.