# Mysql docker failed to start

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a vm created with azure docker ce template. When I run a mysql container with command `docker run --name mysql --privileged=true -v /home/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password" -d mysql:5.7`. It keep failed.

When I run `docker logs mysql`, I can get following messages:

> Initializing database
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:49.780420Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:50.075660Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790 2019-02-21T14:21:50.148855Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:50.544693Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID:
>   07752ed0-35e4-11e9-8ebf-0242ac110003.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:50.550825Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:50.551404Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310662Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode. 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310747Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310765Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310797Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310814Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310826Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@
>   root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310873Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user
>   mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:51.310887Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry
>   'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>   Database initialized Initializing certificates Generating a RSA
>   private key 
>   ..................................+++++ ........................................................+++++ unable
>   to write 'random state' writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
>   ----- Generating a RSA private key .................................+++++ ..........+++++ unable to write
>   'random state' writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
>   ----- Generating a RSA private key ..+++++ ...............................................................+++++
>   unable to write 'random state' writing new private key to
>   'client-key.pem'
>   ----- Certificates initialized MySQL init process in progress... 2019-02-21T14:21:56.310409Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit
>   DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2019-02-21T14:21:56.330455Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld
>   5.7.25) starting as process 88 ... 2019-02-21T14:21:56.354884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
>   2019-02-21T14:21:56.354945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   GCC atomic builtins 2019-02-21T14:21:56.354958Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses
>   event mutexes 2019-02-21T14:21:56.354968Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin
>   __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.354976Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use
>   zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.354984Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux
>   native AIO
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.355744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of
>   pools: 1
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.356546Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.369564Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing
>   buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.418677Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization
>   of buffer pool 2019-02-21T14:21:56.439895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the
>   mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can
>   be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.458773Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file
>   format is Barracuda. 2019-02-21T14:21:56.522856Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.526137Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1'
>   size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.556301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is
>   now 12 MB. 2019-02-21T14:21:56.566414Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo
>   rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:56.566457Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback
>   segment(s) are active. 2019-02-21T14:21:56.575330Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Waiting for purge to start 2019-02-21T14:21:56.733814Z 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 2019-02-21T14:21:56.861939Z 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 2019-02-21T14:21:57.008155Z
>   0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:57.234143Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log
>   sequence number 2524141 2019-02-21T14:21:57.563290Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2019-02-21T14:21:57.747294Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 125:    88 Killed
>   "$@" --skip-networking --socket="${SOCKET}"
>
> MySQL init process in
>   progress...
>
> MySQL init process in progress... MySQL init process in
>   progress...
>
> MySQL init process in progress... MySQL init process in
>   progress...
>
> MySQL init process in progress... MySQL init process in
>   progress...
>
> MySQL init process in progress... MySQL init process in
>   progress...
>
> MySQL init process in progress... MySQL init process in
>   progress...
>
> MySQL init process in progress...
>
> MySQL init process failed.

Comment: My hypothesis:  `unable to write 'random state' writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'` is indication of problem with access rights. Look at [using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean). Recomendation is to remove `.rnd` file in home directory. In your case it must be the $HOME of user `mysql`. Can you check this hypothesis?

Comment: @AlexYu, finally, I increase my azure vm with more memory, then run the container successfully.